# T-SQL: create stored procedure to update column in table with table and field as params in

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I want to cleanse some columns in a table of a massive database with random data. I have created a stored procedure `CreateRandomString` to create random data (to replace client names etc so we can use the data as a demo). Now I want to create the stored procedure that will take a table name and a column name and replace all the data in that column with random values (each column with a different random value).

I have done mySQL and Oracle in the past, but am now working in SQL Server, and I am stuck with the updating etc. I will not know the key etc on the table, as this is passed in as a parameter.

What I have so far:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC SanitiseData
    (@DataColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @DataTableName NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RandomString NVARCHAR(MAX)

    ;WITH r AS
    (
         EXEC('SELECT ' + @DataColumnName + ', rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @DataColumnName + ') - 1
               FROM ' + @DataTableName)
    )
```

And to get a random string I just do:

```
EXEC CreateRandomString @RandomString = @RandomString OUTPUT
```

However, I can't use an `EXEC` there, so how can I use variables for table and field names, and then how can I loop through and update each row with a different value?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you are looking for. Using unique identifiers to splatter your data with meaningless values though you could modify that as you see fit.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC SanitiseData
        (@DataColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX),
         @DataTableName NVARCHAR(MAX))
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1024) = 'UPDATE ' + @DataTableName + ' SET ' +  @DataColumnName + ' = CAST(NEWID() as varchar(36))';
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END;
```

Comment: This is good, but I need to get the value from the stored procedure so I can tweak how the values are created. This means I need to generate a new value for each record from the stored procedure.

Comment: This will generate a new value for each record.

Comment: If you want to get the results of this call back out you could add an output clause ie output inserted.* or inserted.@DataColumnName

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this query can be work :

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC SanitiseData
    (@DataColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @DataTableName NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
@Query = 'SELECT ' + @DataColumnName + ', rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @DataColumnName + ') - 1
               FROM ' + @DataTableName
    Exec(@Query)
```

Sory for bad understanding :

You cas performing a update query dynamically like the query perform select.

```
@Query='Update ' + @tablename +f'set' + @collname + ‘ =´ + @newvalue + ´where ‘ +@whereclause
```

And then exec @query

```
Exec(@query)
```

EDIT for user function on update example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufAleaRandomString (@InputValue     varchar(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetourValue varchar(MAX)
    SELECT @RetourValue = @InputValue + 'SomeModificationValue'
    RETURN @RetourValue
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   KeyTransacFull      varchar(50) 
  );  
GO  


INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 1, '|H000021|B1|'

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 2, '|H000021|B1|'


SELECT * FROM #MyTable


UPDATE #MyTable SET KeyTransacFull = dbo.ufAleaRandomString(KeyTransacFull) 

SELECT * FROM #MyTable

DROP TABLE  #MyTable
```

RESULT :

```
PrimaryKey     KeyTransacFull
1             |H000021|B1|
2             |H000021|B1|


PrimaryKey       KeyTransacFull
1               |H000021|B1|SomeModificationValue
2               |H000021|B1|SomeModificationValue
```

Comment: But this means every row will have the value of @newvalue. The point is I want to get a different value from the stored procedure for every record.

Comment: You can change your stored procedure that provided the @newvalue to a function and return the new calculated value and then you call the function getNewValue(@param) on the Update clause

Comment: Change CreateRandomString to function that return varchar and call this on set clause off the update

Comment: @MicWit Hi, i have edit to use random function on update, you can use this way if i understand what you want.